# Fullcalender - Greater Date should not be Dragable behind the Smaller Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have Dates like:

Start Date : 2013-12-04

End Date   : 2013-12-06

Now I want to put a restriction that Smaller Date should not be Dragged after Bigger Date and Bigger Date should not be dragged before smaller Date.

Is this possible to implement ?

**Here is my code so far:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            editable: true,

            events: "json-data.php",

            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(Dragged)');
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: Yes. It is. If you try.

Comment: Show your code, whatever you've attempted so far... I'm not gonna write the whole thing for you

Comment: alright I am providing my current code

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [documentation on `eventDrop`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) : the `eventDrop` callback receives among its arguments a `revertFunc` function, which, when called, reverts the event back to its original position.

Here is an outline of how you can write your `eventDrop` callback :

```
eventDrop : function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
    var smaller = /* get date of (moved) smaller event */,
        bigger = /* get date of (moved) bigger event */;
    if ( smaller > bigger ) {
        alert('smaller should stay before bigger');
        revertFunc();
    }
}
```

Comment: The smaller date is not moving to small date

Comment: @CodeHunter: I don't understand your comment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'revertFunc' (documentation [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/))

Put something like this in `eventDrop`

```
if (initialDate.getTime()>finalDate.getTime()) {revertFunc();}
```

`getTime` is to get the number of milliseconds passed since 1970(this is used for comparing two dates)
And by `initialDate` and `finalDate` I'm referring to the initial(drag start) and final(drag end) `Date` instances. In this case you can probably replace that init/final check by

`if (dayDelta<0)`

`dayDelta` is predefined in `fullcalendar`

Comment: I've added a little explanation. You should read the documentation thoroughly